# Installation of Ruby-OAuth pkg with Ruby gems more platform independently?

Tags: ruby, oauth, rubygems, debian, package-managers

I want to get this package ruby-auth [here](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/ruby-oauth/oauth.1.en.html), originally developed for Debian, working more platform-independtly. I am able to use it with Debian but macOS's brew package manager does not contain it. I would like to get the same tool working more platform-independently so trying to get the oauth working from gems but the errors below.

**How to get the Oauth1 command line tool working more platform-independent way?**

*Ruby Gems leading to some error*

> Can I get the oauth tool somehow to work with gems pkg-manager?
>
> ```
> $ gem install oauth
> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
>     You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
> ```
>
> and even with sudo some error (I would like to avoid using sudo, not to mess up the originals)
>
> ```
> $ sudo gem install oauth
> $ oauth 
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
> ```
>
> `require': cannot load such file --
>   active_support/core_ext/string/inflections (LoadError)
>         from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'
>         from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/oauth-0.5.3/lib/oauth/cli.rb:8:in `<top
>   (required)>'
>         from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'
>         from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require'
>         from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/oauth-0.5.3/bin/oauth:4:in`'
>         from /usr/local/bin/oauth:23:in `load'
>         from /usr/local/bin/oauth:23:in`'

Comment: it might rely on activesupport being installed without actually doing it. Try `sudo gem install activesupport` first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the activesupport dependency doubt, as commented by max pleaner, such that

```
gem install activesupport oauth
```

and this fixed the oauth's LoadError in both `macOS` and `Windows 10 Enterprise`. In Windows 10, I used the newest 2.4.1 installation medium of [RubyInstaller.org](https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/).